# Mobile website for iOS: deeplink to native FB share

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to deeplink into the Facebook app on iOS from a mobile website to open a share dialog with a predefined URL and message? I couldn't find this in the Facebook Developer manuals, but I have the feeling it should be possible.

Comment: No it is not possible. Prefilling the message is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: And sharing a URL without the message or even completely without URL? How would I be able to open up the native FB sharing experience on iOS?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't open up the native share dialog from a website